# Is "What the earliest time sounds good to you?" correct?

Tags: questions

I know that if you are asking about the subject, you don't use the auxiliary verb. For instance, we ask

> What time tomorrow sounds good to you to meet?

But here when I wanted to ask about the earliest time you can meet, I feel the compulsion to use the auxiliary verb "is" after "what".

> What is the earliest time tomorrow that sounds good to you to meet?

But I keep saying to myself this wrong because of the addition of "is". However, if I omit it, it sounds as if something is missing.

> What the earliest time tomorrow sounds good to you to meet?

Am I wrong in my feeling?

Comment: Stangdon's answer is correct.  Also, you could shorten the sentence for informal settings by omitting "time", as in "What's the earliest you can meet tomorrow?"

Comment: @Kevin In that case, I would change "What's …" to "When is …"

Comment: @200_success Either "what" or "when" sounds equally fine to me in that situation.  "time" is implied when using "what"

Answer (score 3):

> What is the earliest time tomorrow that sounds good to you to meet?

is perfectly correct.  Yes, you have to use "is".  Think of it this way: you wouldn't say "What your name?" or "What the answer?", would you?  It's a simple question: *What is (noun-phrase)?*  that just looks more complicationed than it is, because  in this case, noun-phrase is "the earliest time that sounds good to you to meet."